# Observe contents of ArrayDeque

Tags: android, observable, android-livedata

I have a MutableLiveData of type ArrayDeque.
I am trying to observe it.
It works when I first assign a value to it (create the ArrayDeque) but what I am trying to do is observe changes to the contents i.e. when new entries are added or when entries are removed.

```
var moveHistory = MutableLiveData<ArrayDeque<Move>>()

..

    moveHistory.value = ArrayDeque<Move>()  <<--- this fires
    moveHistory.value?.addFirst(MontanaMoveStandard(from, to)) <<- this doesn't fire
```

this is my observe code:

```
        moveHistory.observe(this, Observer {
            moveHistory -> undoButton?.isEnabled = moveHistory.size > 0
    })
```

Comment: LiveData  is not going to trigger the observer when you manually change the contents of the object is references. You probably want something like this: val data = moveHistory.value; data?.addFirst(MontanaMoveStandard(from, to)); moveHistory.value = data;

Comment: @Luksprog Yeah. Problem is that there are many places in the program where I update moves

Comment: You can abstract the code above into an extension property/function on the MutableLiveData class.

Comment: @Luksprog Didn't think of that. What I did in the end was to create a class that extends MutableLiveData and then override the methods on "value". Making them extension functions would probably have been neater. Maybe I will do it some day. :)

Answer (score 0):

This what I did in the end.

I made my own class MoveHistory which extends MutableLiveData and perform the actions on that. I added to it the methods I use (addFirst and pollFirst) and then reassign value to itself as suggested by Luksprog

This is the class I ended up with:

```
class MoveHistory(): Serializable, MutableLiveData<ArrayDeque<Move>>(){
    init {
        value = ArrayDeque<Move>()
    }

    fun addFirst(move: Move) {
        value?.addFirst(move)
        value = value
    }
    fun pollFirst(): Move {
        var move = value?.pollFirst()
        value = value
        return move!!
    }
}
```

Now all I have to do is register my observer on an instance of that class and use the methods to add and remove.